# GNU GRAB problem in single os Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, grub2

I have Dell laptop and os is ubuntu 14.04. Suddenly my machine showing black screen with the title " GNU GRAB version 2.02 beta2-9ubuntu1.12" below this four option as 'Ubuntu, Advanced options for Ubuntu, Memory test (memtest86+) and Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)'. When i booting by selecting Ubuntu option it showing error with 'initramfs' promt. I didn't do an partition. Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Advanced options for Ubuntu in it enter to recovery mode and upgrade Grub. If it will not work then use third party tool eg Boot repair disk, which is live CD about 600mb. Mandatory condition is it should be connected with WiFi before repairing boot loader.It will automatically scan your all bootable drives and will give you instructions on the spot. A menu will come where mouse will not work. In that condition you have to use tab to move courser and space to select. Good luck.